# How to change the src of multiple ImageButtons on a single ImageButton click

Tags: android, imagebutton, android-imagebutton

I know how to change the src of an `ImageButton` when clicked, however I want to also change the src of another `ImageButton` at that time. I have no clue how to go about accessing the `ImageButton` that was NOT clicked. I know it's ID.

Edit: It may be good to mention that I will have multiple buttons, so it's not just a certain button that I need to change. Both the ones I need to change will differ.

Comment: Change the src of the ImageButtons in the onClickListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok lets think we have two `ImageButton` like `ImageButtonA` and `ImageButtonB`. When user click ImageButtonA we have to change the src of ImageButtonB. Lets make two class variable for `ImageButtonA` and `ImageButtonB`.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

private ImageButton imageButtonA,ImageButtonB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.myactivity);

        imageButtonA= (ImageButton ) findViewById(R.id.image_button_a);
        imageButtonB= (ImageButton ) findViewById(R.id.image_button_b);

        imageButtonA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
             imageButtonB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mysourceImage);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

I think it will solve your problem. And if you want to change multiple `ImageButton` src then you can make multiple `ImageButton` class variable.

Comment: I guess I was too vague about my intentions for my code, so I did something else instead, which worked. But this is a good answer to my stated question, thank you.